# Data Driven Coded UI test: How to set datasource for Access database (oledb)?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-access, oledb, datasource

I wrote a Visual Studio data driven coded UI test that uses data from an Excel spreadsheet.

The connection looks like this:

```
   [TestMethod, DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", @"Dsn=Excel Files;Driver=(Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};
    dbq=C:\Test Deliverables\Flydekasser\Data\Flydekasser beregning.xls;
    defaultdir=C:\Test Deliverables\Flydekasser\Data;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "kasse beregning$",
                DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem(@"C:\Test Deliverables\Flydekasser\Data\Flydekasser beregning.xls")]
```

However, now I would like to get it to use data from an Access database (oledb).

Can anyone help me to change my code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself:

```
[TestMethod, DataSource("System.Data.OleDb", "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\\C# træning\\CUIT\\Flydekasser_1\\Flydekasser\\Flydekasser\\FlydekasserBeregning.accdb", "kasse_beregning", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem(@"C:\Test Deliverables\Flydekasser\Data\FlydekasserBeregning.accdb") ]
```